# Which tense to use with if clause

Tags: conditionals, technical

I need to describe what a thing does. I have the following expression:

```
It deletes photos from the Favorites database if the user didn't undo "Remove all" action.
```

Is it correct? Should I use here "hasn't undone" instead or maybe conditionals? I'm confused.

Comment: Since you use present for the first clause, present perfect is good for the second (earlier) time in the next clause. _Hasn't undone_ (or maybe _hasn't already undone_). And it should be _the "remove all" action_. The article is necessary here.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you

Comment: *It deletes photos from the Favourites database if "Remove All" is selected.* Saying *the user didn't undo* and *action* is awkward.

Comment: @JasonBassford yeah I also don't like that part but it gives some more info